Ideas for an alternative to nuclear weapons as a deterrent?
I posted a question a couple days ago about the use of bio-weapons as an alternative to nuclear weapons as a deterrent for a D&D campaign I'm working on.
I got some really good answers explaining why bio-weapons aren't really suitable for use as a deterrent which is a shame.
So, since bio-weapons are off the table, I'm looking for some other ideas for a credible deterrent that a small(ish) but relatively well funded state could create.
Nuclear material is scarce and heavily regulated so the two main superpowers in this world essentially have exclusive control over the worlds limited supply of it.
Think Switzerland but with half the GDP, a tiny country nestled in the mountains with other countries surrounding it and two superpowers bordering either side of those countries. It's smack damn in the middle of two rivals that have been engaged in proxy wars for decades, so inevitably those conflicts spill into the country in question which is bad.
So now they want a deterrent to dissuade the superpowers and some of their neighbors from attempting military action near or within their borders. Something that keeps other countries on their toes, be more careful not to accidentally cross into their territory and especially not to invade.
I'm planning on setting it in 2065, so a bit in the future but not so far that's its pure sci-fi.
It doesn't have to be something that ends the world, it just has to make the inevitable retaliation after invading/attacking not worth it.
But it has to be a weapon, that's pivotal to the main story arc.
I was thinking maybe some sort of extremely potent nerve agent like Sarin or VX that's somehow been modified to make dispersal exponentially more efficient? Its a bit boring but realistic I guess.
Nano bots are another cool idea but would it even be possible to weaponize them by 2065?

I don't have an answer myself but some analysis on what properties make atomic bombs the great deterrent they are: Terrible, devastating, large area of effect, immediate, lasting effect and "has already been demonstrated". Missing any of these properties would probably not result in even close to the deterring effect of atomic bombs.

I am perplexed: you state in the question that it has to be a weapon, then accept an answer which describes something which is not a weapon.

@L.Dutch I accepted that answer because its clever, its technically not a weapon which actually makes writing it into the story easier. But when used with a different payload, it becomes a weapon capable of taking out entire constellations of satellites before anyone has a chance to even launch their nukes. Or hell, throw tungsten rods on it, orbital bombardment anyone?
But there's also incentive for other countries not to attack it, its the cheapest way of getting to space. So its not one, but three deterrents.
It also just fits in a near future setting, dirty bombs do not.

@RadovanGarabík I saw that post already, there's some cool ideas in that thread but I was kind of hoping for something a bit more sci-fi seeing as this is set in 2065 as I said in my post.

Since you raise Switzerland, (Taiwan is similarish.) Why not the hedgehog approach, the goal of which is to make attack very costly.

This question does not seem to be about the rules of your world. It seems to be solving the puzzle that you wrote yourself into. Questions like that are story-based (off-topic), and this seems confirmed by "it has to be a weapon, that's pivotal to the main story arc"

I'm ambivalent about closing this - to me it seems sufficiently well specified to find an answer that fits, but is story-idea generating at it's base. It bugs me that I should vote to close this as it's the sort of question I like to try and answer. VTC, out of duty, not because I want to.

Your country has huge mass drivers (rocket launch sites with sleds) on high mountains, enabling extremely cheap launches of supplies into space. In an era where space colonization is progressing, these mass drivers function like canals, facilitating transport from the ground to space.
Opposing the country would mean halting the use of the mass drivers, forcing the adversary to rely on less efficient launch methods. In the worst-case scenario, the country might retaliate by using mass drivers to launch anti-satellite weapons and create Kessler syndrome.
To avoid battles in space and catastrophic consequences, citizens of neighboring countries (especially those living in space settlements) are against their governments provoking this country, even if they could win the war.

Ohhhhh that's actually really clever, they build them under the guise of being simply a new means of getting stuff into orbit so nobody questions them.
By the time they're complete, its too late, anyone tries anything and a lot of very useful orbits suddenly become unusable :)

@ChellCPlus It is customary to wait 24 hours until you accept an answer. Otherwise you discourage other people from answering.

@TheDyingOfLight Oh, is it a rule? I actually quite like this answer, it's probably what I'll end up using.

@ChellCPlus Not a hard and fast one, but it is somewhat of a convention. There a people in a bunch of time zones, so to get the best answers, you wanna give everyone a chance.

For putting something into orbit mass drivers can only replace the first stage of a 2 stage rocket system.  Acceleration near the Earths surface can only raise the apogee of an orbit,  To keep it from falling back you also need to accelerate near apogee to raise the perigee; if not you end up coming back down to the surface a half orbit later.  (Or you're going so fast you escape earth orbit entirely and fly off into interplanetary space.)

Various people have claimed to have invented "the weapon which will put an end to all wars" over the centuries, but only the nuke has ensured, so far, that nobody wanted really to use it again.
If it cannot be nuke, maybe you can try with an anti-matter bomb: annihilating matter with anti-matter releases a huge amount of energy, even more than an equivalent nuke or fusion bomb. But... I doubt that a tiny GDP nation can manage to produce enough anti-matter to fire a decent bomb, let alone to fund all the technology needed to reach that point.
I am afraid you have put yourself in a Kobayashi Maru situation with your constraints.

Strategic Greenhouse Effect Weapons
Chemical warfare is a good idea, but you are not targeting correctly. Don't aim at soldiers or population, aim at the Ecology.
Losing the Ozone layer is devastating for a Planet. As are 10 degrees of climate change within a year.
Essentially, we are using chemical industry and terra-forming techniques to, well... Un-terraform the planet.
The plan is this. The country need to state sponsor th development of chemical industry. The facilities must be made multi purpose. And capable of producing CFCs and SF6.
About 10 million tons of CFCs should whipe out the Ozone layer. This will cause damage to plant live all over the world and massive increases in skin cancer.
CF6 is an extremely potent greenhouse gas. It is 23.500 times more efficient than CO2. Dumping 10 to 50 million tons of it into the atmosphere could raise the global temperature by maybe 10 degrees.
Is this industrially feasible? Yes. Globally we produce 250 million tons of Sulfuric Acid each year. Given the massive state sponsorship of chemical industry we need here, this scheme might actually be profitable as well.
The bottleneck is probably Fluorine production. Globally we mine about 7 million tons of CaF2. This can be upgraded with investment into mining.
How to do It
Strategic Economic planning is essential here. This scheme could be hidden under a push for becoming the global hub for chemical industry. But from the construction of the facilities to upscaling of CaF2 mining, into the gas production we are talking a long time.
Having chemical storage vats of both of the gasses ready that can be blown up if the nation is invaded will take something between 10 and 30 years. Not much different from running a nuclear weapons program.
You prepare this in secret, and as soon as you are confident that you can ruin the climate, you announce your new deterrace policy to everyone.
Additionally,being a hub for chemical industry is valuable on the soft power front. Underselling the markets of both superpowers in certain vital industrial chemicals makes an attack on you more difficult. And if they start stockpiling, you have a smoke sensor for aggression.
Strategic Implications
This is a very situational strategic deterrace. If you country is geographically relatively robust to climate change or climate Sims tell you that you will suffer less, you can do this. You also really want to set up your infrastructure to be climate change proof.
You are also indescriminately fucking over everyone. Nukes are bad enough, this is worse. You are threatening to end civilization if you get attacked.
Secrecy is vital while setting this up. Everyone has an incentive to prevent you from doing this.
Even worse, you are hitting a complex system, the climate with a big hammer. And you are pushing it into a high entropy state. There might be catastrophic feedback loops. Decomposing biomass from the global forrests you killed. Changes in planetary albedo. Ocean Acidification. Runaway collapse of deep sea methane-hydrates.
On the bad end, you are looking at triggering something like the End-Permian Mass Extinction. Or even a straight transition into a wet-house or greenhouse climate regime. Effectivly turning the world into Venus. You better be really sure how much gas you are releasing.

This is a really cool idea that I might use in a different story but its a tiny bit overkill. In the campaign I'm writing, part of the story involves the players sabotaging the "weapon" and disabling it. I can't really see a way of sabotaging what you've described. Strangely enough its a bit too good.

I've upvoted anyhow because its a really well thought out answer

@ChellCPlus It's a command and controll system you want to sabotage. You want it to be robust to trigger it reliably, but not that it's trivial to trigger. Terrorism is a concern. So sabotaging the controll software would work. Think Stuxnet.

How about a virus targeting major internet infrastructure?  Maybe the country's cyberwarfare division has cooked up a virus capable of infecting and bricking Tier 1 servers.
Frying a lot of these would cause a severe disruption to the internet.  Not as flashy as nuclear weapons, but the economic damage would be enormous.  I mean, I assume in the 2060's, the internet will be even more vital than it is today; and breaking it and knocking the world back to ~1970 would be catastrophic.  Even better if it could be discriminate; you could just threaten to kick your opposition off the internet, rather than the entire world.
Perhaps the virus has already infected these servers, and your D&D party is on a mission to sabotage the system that sends the "Kill the internet" command.

Dirty Bomb
So, what you want is something that makes a small nation tell the super-nations "If you do anything bad to us, bad things will happen to you", and by "bad things" you mean something that causes great harm to the offenders, correct?
Well then...
Smuggle in a dirty bomb
Creating / acquiring radioactive materials of sufficient activity and quantity is a doddle, even for a small to medium sized nation. Smuggle that into one or more of the major population / business / industry / food production centers, attach it to a dispersal system, like a bomb or otherwise sufficiently effective mechanism, and then – quietly – inform the major power of your doings. Also, let them know that these Dirty Bombs operate on a Dead Man's Switch scheme, so that they demand an active input at a certain interval, or they will go off.
If you want to mix things up, set the to power blocs against each other. If bloc A does something against you, it will also set off the Dead Man's Switch against bloc B, and vice versa. And you let both blocs know that you have done the same against both of them.
It does not even have to be an actual threat, you can just claim you will do it, and threaten to broadcast that to the general population, or just start rumors, and watch was fear and paranoia causes bloc A and B descend into chaos as people flee the "targeted" areas. A small, controlled and harmless demonstration release of the materials in question gives physical, tangible evidence that you have the materials.
Granted, there are so many things that could go wrong with this scheme.
...i.e. plot hooks!
Hope this helps. :)

The Swiss have a conventional solution that has worked since Roman times. It has mountains on much of its border. It has national service for all men. It has a weapons cache every few houses. Every hospital has a giant bunker underneath it. Many of those picturesque mountains have underground fortresses and railway lines.
This sends the message: you don't want our land. It is not on the way to anywhere. You can't farm it. It is chock full of nutters who will make you pay dearly for every step you take. When you have conquered everywhere else, come back and we will see how hard you actually are. But until then, there are places you would rather go, and things you would rather do.

The Romans did conquer the territory of modern Switzerland... But yes, conquering a well-armed well-fortified mountainous country is a pain. (And everybody loves Swiss banks, anyway, so that nobody wants to interfere with the business.)

I did specify it has to be a weapon though, its kind of a big part of the overarching story. The players can't steal a bunker from under a hospital.

Don't forget the "We also have a shitton of banks. Nice Economy you have there, would be a shame if something happened to it.."

Asteroids
I'm kinda surprised no one has thought of this, but this is probably a time when weaponizing asteroids is possible(expensive, but possible). Attach some engines to some small asteroids(They don't need to be that big to be cause for concern, 100m is a country killer, and 10m could take out most of a city center). You can do a demonstration impacting the Pacific (Not a small target to hit). You don't even need to be particularly accurate, if it lands in the general area of the target that'll likely be a good enough deterrent if you have a large enough asteroid. Also, nearby countries will be very invested in making sure no one makes you angry since the blowback could affect them.

Even before they had nuclear weapons, North Korea was able to deter any action against them by having vast quantities of conventional weapons, including probably some chemical weapons- enough to overwhelm any possible defence. Probably the risk of intervention was highest at the point just before they achieved a usable nuclear capability including delivery systems.
By 2065 I would think you could realistically have vast swarms of inexpensive diverse (diverse so no one weakness could defeat them) autonomous robots/drones that would overwhelm defences in the target aggressors. They can be autonomous and vision based or vision assisted so they cannot be spoofed, called back or defeated by knocking out GNSS navigation. Large quantities can be hidden under mountains and in tunnels so that even a nuclear first-strike is not guaranteed to get all, or even most, of them.
Think of land mines that don't wait for you to come to them. They could deliver small amounts of chemical weapons, biological or chemical anti-crop weapons or small (non-nuclear) EMP weapons to specific locations, and choose when to release their payloads by measuring things like local wind conditions, as well as just blowing things up. They could be personalized to seek out particular politicians, business and military figures, the identities and signatures of which are public knowledge.
To achieve that end, the small country would specialize in the production of robotic components and robotic technology for every application, including swarming algorithms and difficult-to-jam inter-robot communication.  They could be credibly demonstrated in dual-use conditions such as deforesting an area or ridding it of pests such as feral pigs in a very short period of time, and adequate details leaked that nobody would want to mess with them. Perhaps a particular bear that has been threatening humans is taken down by a team of stealthy drones using facial and gait recognition. The opposing stocky and hairy Minister of Defence might get the message.

This is a D&D setting? Assuming you want to avoid macic, fair enough. However as it's been pointed out in other posts, you are painting yourself into a corner. You will have to resort to magic in the form of fantastic science to get out of that corner anyway. Maybe a marriage of the two considering the setting.
No magic fine, but this is a D&D universe. Perhaps someone in this small country, a tormented Tesla like figure, stumbled across the secret to access one of the fundamental sources of magic, the Positive/Negative material plains. Not in a sophisticated way even approaching the complexity of a cantrip, but a clumbsy hamfisted way. Slamming a blob of positive and negative energy together, the outcome will be anything but uneventful.
I can't find any set cannon laws of how the interaction would go. However it would take little imagination to take the ability to weaponize access to one or both of these energies.

Well, I mean its not actually set in the D&D universe, it just uses the D&Ds rules and mechanics with a custom story, weapons, some new mechanics etc. Its homebrew ya know?

Sabotaging nuclear power plants
If the country runs nuclear power, these plants can be leveraged as stationary nuclear "bombs" of sorts. It doesn't need an explosion, just sufficient release of nuclear material or radiation is sufficient to make them suffer a lot (like Chernobyl and Fukushima); this could be done either via hacking or sabotage teams.
Sabotaging water supply
Similar to above: sabotage the critical infrastructure around drinking water. Introduce poisoning at the sources, be that chemical or biological poisoning. This works on a smaller scale than nukes, but can send whole towns into disarray, and draw a lot of ressources
Access to an orbital mirror or similar power source
Mirrors in Earth orbit could be used to beam down energy into a receiver. Thus harvesting more solar energy than available on ground. This tech exists on paper. These devices will need very careful pointing control and could be leveraged as potent orbital weapons, burning whole areas with easy swipes (purposefully or by accident). The idea could be modified by not being a direct mirror but huge solar panel which beam down a microwave or laser beam for digestion of the ground receiver. That would also ease the control as weapon and at the same time offer more safety.

Would that not actually incentivize them to invade?

Facts don't give incentive to invade. You just have (someone) to frame it correctly. Call it terrorism. Blame some occurances or happenings on them... There always has to be some (perceived) geo-strategical gain for someone in the background

But its supposed to be a deterrent? Like its meant to stop the country from getting attacked in the first place. Blowing up nuclear plants is vengeance for when you're people are already dead.

Right... maybe the capability alone is not the best deterrent. I added another idea :)

I don't know if you could make a modern plant fail in a destructive enough way, even if you wanted to and had full access, short of cutting open the reactor and blowing up the insides(Which is a heck of a sabotage operation to cut through 20ft of concrete undetected).
